# How to efficiently make a function call to each row of a 2D ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, traversal, knn

I'm implementing a KNN classifier and need to quickly traverse the test set to calculate and store their predicted labels.

The way I use now is to use the list comprehension to get a list, and then turn it into a ndarray, similar to `np.array([predict(point) for point in test_set])`, but I think it takes time and space, because the for loop of Python is relatively slow and it needs to create another copy. Is there a more efficient way to get such an array?
I know that numpy has `apply_along_axis` function, but it is said that it only implicitly uses the for loop, which may not improve the performance.

**EDIT**: I learned a possible way to save memory: match np.fromiter() function and generator, like `np.fromiter((predict(point) for point in test_set), int, test_set.shape[0])`, which avoids creating a list halfway. Unfortunately, in my program, it seems to run a little slower than the previous method.

Comment: Have you profiled your code to support your conclusion that this is what's slowing it down?

Comment: The for loop in Pythonis indeed much slower than the vectorization operation in ndarray, which I obviously felt after modifying my other codes.

Comment: The slowness of the loop isn't the loop mechanism itself, but the need to call `predict()` many times.  As long as that function only works with one row at a time, there isn't much you can do to improve speed.  Loops aren't inherently bad; a few iterations on a complex task can actually be faster than something that operates on a whole array.  What you want to avoid is many iterations on a relatively simple task, one that can be performed with whole-array `numpy` methods and operators.

Answer (score 0):

the good old way:

```py
def my_func(test_set):
  i = 0
  test_set_size = len(test_set)
  result = [None] * test_set_size
  while i < test_set_size:
    result[i] = predict(test_set[i])
    i = i + 1
  return np.array(result)
```

Comment: Why not just create a ndarray of the same size?